# setting the working directory of eclipse rcp application with a commandline argument

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to set the working directory (not the workspace) of the eclipse RCP application.

It will be of great help if I get this info.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Eclipse RCP does not have a command line argument to set the current working directory. You will need to arrange for this to be set before starting the RCP.

You can set the workspace location using the `-data workspace-path` argument.